# if else statements

Tags: php, forms, validation, input, laravel

I am using Laravel php framework and i have a form with 2 upload fields. The fields work normally and theres no problems. The .php code is as following.

PS. For those who are not familiar with the curly braces, its basically just `<?php echo .... ?>` in the blade template engine.

The code

```
{{  Form::label('upload_files', 'Lataa bändin LAVAKARTTA, esim .jpg (tiedosto      pakollinen)'); }}
{{  Form::file('upload_files', '', array('class' => 'form-field', 'form-text')); }}

{{  Form::label('upload_files_raider', 'Lataa bändin tekninen RAIDERI esim .txt (tiedosto pakollinen)'); }}
{{  Form::file('upload_files_raider', '', array('class' => 'form-field', 'form-text')); }}
```

After the form is submitted i pass the contents (files) to my upload directory.

In my Controller i have this code:

```
$a = $formsubmit['esiintyva_artisti'];

// if no file dont upload
// $a is used to give the filename a ending that correspons to a user

if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
// if (!isset($_FILES)) {
    Input::upload('upload_files', 'public/uploads', $a . '-artistin-tai-bandin-lavakartta.jpg');
};

if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
// if (!isset($_FILES)) {
    Input::upload('upload_files_raider', 'public/uploads', $a . '-artistin-tai-bandin-raideri.txt');
};
```

Heres the problem:

When I submit the form WITHOUT any uploaded files I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object in /var/www/...../laravel/input.php on line 230

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably coming from you checking the **$_FILES['image']** array when it hasn't been set, since you use **upload_files** and **upload_files_raider** in your form. Try checking for an upload file by using Input::file('upload_files'):

```
if (! is_null(Input::file('upload_files'))) {
    Input::upload('upload_files', 'public/uploads', $a.'-artistin-tai-bandin-lavakartta.jpg');
}

if (! is_null(Input::file('upload_files_raider'))) {
   Input::upload('upload_files_raider', 'public/uploads', $a.'-artistin-tai-bandin-raideri.txt');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was easily solved just by checking for `null`, `if` statements as:

```
if ($file_upload == null) {
    return View::make('site.form')
        ->with('message', 'Choose the file to be uploaded!');
} else {
    Input::upload('file_upload', 'public/uploads', $date.' '.$upload_file_name);
}
```